# A line through $P$ meets $\overline{QR}$ at $S$ and meets the circumcircle of $\triangle PQR$ at $T$. Prove $PS\cdot ST=QS\cdot SR$.

Tags: geometry

> A straight line through the vertex $P$ of $\triangle PQR$ intersects the side $QR$ at the point $S$ and meets the circumcircle of the $\triangle PQR$ at the point $T$. If $S$ is not the centre of the circumcircle, then prove that
>
> $$PS \cdot ST=QS \cdot SR$$

The following formula is mentioned in books, $PT\cdot QR=PR\cdot TQ+PQ\cdot RT$. I cannot prove $PS \cdot ST = QS \cdot SR$.

Comment: Hint. $\triangle STQ\sim\triangle SRP$.

Comment: reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "formula mentioned in books" is Ptolemy's theorem, but unnecessary here. As the comments suggest, joining $TR$, then$$\triangle SPQ\sim\triangle SRT$$making$$\frac{PS}{SR}=\frac{QS}{ST}$$whence$$PS\cdot ST=QS\cdot SR$$